# Inserting data into two databases, where one is a third party

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I need to insert data into two different databases. One is locally, and the other is a third party CRM that provides me with path to their php file. This is the code I am right now using to insert data into their database.

```
     <form accept-charset='ISO-8859-1' enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1' name='opt_in_form' id='opt_in_form' action='https://www.thirdpartyurl.com/index.php' method='post'>

 <input type='text' id='somevalue' name='somevalue'></p>
 <input type='text' id='somevalue' name='somevalue'></p>
 <input type='text' id='somevalue' name='somevalue'></p>
 </form>
```

How do I grab the same data and dump it into another php that feeds a local MySQL? Can I call two actions in the  ? Or do I have to do something else?

Comment: You could use javascript and ajax the data to another database on form submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to insert data in 2 databases, you have to do 2 actions. One local action, and one "remote" action.

Possibilty:

- Create a php file on your own server where you POST the values to
- This PHP has to do a POST to the 3rd party URL (i.e. by using curl, http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)
- Insert the values into the local database (i.e. MySQL database?)